# How can I submit a form and then have the browser return to the same place on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to create a form that when submitted, sends the data and then when the page reloads the user is returned to the same place on the page they were before submitting the form using either javascript or jquery.

Comment: How about using ajax to submit the form and never leaving the page at all?

Comment: Unfortunately that is not an option for me since the site is being run by Liferay.

Comment: If you have access to change/add javascript you can stop the default form submission and trigger an ajax submission

Comment: If you have control over the HTML for the `<form>`, add a hash tag to the action: `<form action="http://example.com/foo/bar#jump_me_to_this_element>`, then make sure you have an HTML tag Id on that page with the same value as the hash tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested, but you would do something along the lines of:

```
$(function() {
    var lst = localStorage.getItem('lastScrollTop');
    if(lst !== null) {
        $(window).scrollTop(lst);
        localStorage.removeItem('lastScrollTop');
    }
    $("form").on('submit', function() {
        //use whatever persistence method you'd like, I'm using HTML5 localStorage for brevity
        localStorage.setItem('lastScrollTop', $(window).scrollTop());
    });
});
```

Comment: I guess would be more accurate to use sessionStorage instead

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is much better to use JQuery as it has lot of inbuilt methods.
I normally use [.ajax as it is very flexible](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) and can be used to GET and POST data very quickly.

Now coming onto how to do it..

```
$.ajax({
    url : "AJAX_POST_URL",
    type: "POST",
    data : formData,  //The best way to formulate is using JSON and server to accept it
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        //data - response from server
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could prevent default submission, then submit using Ajax, so you don't leave the page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // your form
    var $myForm = $('form');

    $myForm.on('submit', function(e){
        // stops the from from submitting and loading a new page.
        e.preventDefault();

        // use jQuery post to post the form fields to the default from action
        $.post($myForm.attr('action'), $myForm.serialize(), function(data){
           console.log(data);
        });
    });
});
```